# Android get device language ISO string

Tags: java, android

I do not know what is the difference between ISO 639-1, 639-2, 639-3 or 639-4. I know that ISO is the international organization for standardization (according to wikipedia).

I need to get the following language (iso-code?) from the device: `en-US`

I have tried:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

but I am getting: `en`

Comment: Check getISO3Language

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Locale bLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build();
```

Comment: I do not want to set the device language

Comment: I do not think this is setting the device language.  It is setting properties on the builder in order to create the 'en-US' locale.